# avoid duplicate values in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a "People You May Know" script in php. This script shows me the friends of my friends, in a php friend system. 
I have a table called **`users (user_id, name, surname, email, profile)`** thats holds information about the users. Another table called **`friends(friend_id, user_one, user_two)`** that holds the id of users that are friends.
My code is the following:

```
<?php
  // ------ gives me my friends

  $friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one`='$session_user_id' OR `user_two`='$session_user_id' ");  

  while($run_friend = mysql_fetch_array($friend_query)){
    $user_one = $run_friend['user_one'];
    $user_two = $run_friend['user_two'];

    if($user_one == $session_user_id){
      $user = $user_two;
    } else {
      $user = $user_one;
    }

    $friend_id = getuser($user, 'user_id');


    // ----- gives me friends of my friends
    $friend_query_two = mysql_query("  SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE (`user_one`='$friend_id' and `user_two` != '$session_user_id') OR (`user_one`!='$session_user_id' and `user_two`='$friend_id' )  ");  

    while($run_friend_two = mysql_fetch_array($friend_query_two)){                          
      $user_one_two = $run_friend_two['user_one'];
      $user_two_two = $run_friend_two['user_two'];

      if($user_one_two == $friend_id){
        $user_two = $user_two_two;
      } else {
        $user_two = $user_one_two;
      }

      $friend_id_two = getuser($user_two, 'user_id');
      // ------- gives me friends of my friends that are my friends also

      $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two='$friend_id_two') OR (user_one='$friend_id_two' AND user_two='$session_user_id')  ");

      if (mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) != 1){ 
        //here is the problem where I get duplicate values about friends of my friends

        $my_friend = $friend_id_two;
        $friends_friends = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE (`user_id`='$my_friend')  ");

        while ($run_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_friends)) {
          $friend_user_id = $run_friends['user_id'];
        }
?>
```

My code works fine and gives me friends of my friends. The problem is that I get some duplicate values. Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `distinct` keyword, as in `select distinct`?

Comment: yes, it did not work. I may use it wrong. Any suggestions how you should use it in my code?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I've seen you on a few questions. Nice comments. Good luck on your crusade. I wish you the best.

Comment: After adding proper indentation: You are missing a lot of closing `}`.

Comment: yes sorry about this I forget to insert before

Comment: `"I got in one little injection attack and my m(u|o)m got scared and said 'you're moving with your aunty and uncle in Bel Aire'"`

Comment: if you have 10 friends and each or your friends has 10 friends that script will do 211 queries, avoid queries within loops wherever possible

Comment: Is it your intent to always retrieve your friends before retrieving your friends' friends? Is the expected output two arrays (one with my friends user_ids and one with my friends' friends user_ids)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

A PHP implementation might look something like this:

```
global $db;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');

$friends = getFriendsOf( $session_user_id );
$friends_of_friends = getFriendsOf( $friends );

// Do whatever you want right here
// with your friends ($friends)
// and your friends' friends ($friends_of_friends)

function getFriendsOf( $user ) {
    global $db;

    if ( is_array( $user ) ) $where = ' IN (' . implode( ',', $user ) . ')';
    else $where = ' = ' . $user;

    $sql = "
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( f.user_id ) as friends
  FROM (SELECT user_one as user_id
          FROM friends
         WHERE user_two {$where}
         UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT user_two
          FROM friends
         WHERE user_one {$where}
       ) f";

    $results = $db->query( $sql );
    $row = $results->fetch();
    return explode( ',', $row[ 'friends' ] );
}
```

**Original**

Don't have any data to test with. But something like this should do the trick.

Get Friends:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM (SELECT user_one as user_id
          FROM friends
         WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
         UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT user_two
          FROM friends
         WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
       ) f
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = f.user_id
```

Get Friends of Friends:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_one as user_id
          FROM friends
         WHERE user_two IN (SELECT user_one as user_id
                              FROM friends
                             WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
                             UNION DISTINCT
                            SELECT user_two
                              FROM friends
                             WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
                           )
         UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT DISTINCT user_two
          FROM friends
         WHERE user_one IN (SELECT user_one as user_id
                              FROM friends
                             WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
                             UNION DISTINCT
                            SELECT user_two
                              FROM friends
                             WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
                           )
       ) f
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = f.user_id
```

Comment: can you please show me, how this will print all the ids that I want. Any idea how to write this after in php?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better with a 'many to many' table for the friends

Like:

```
Table Friends

user Friend
  0    11
  0    58
  0    87
  1    35
  2    44
  2    98
```

then you can `"SELECT Friend FROM Friends WHERE user = $user";`

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your query to use a `UNION` with `SELECT DISTINCT` and only retrieve one user id column for each subquery.

Alternatively you could put the `$user_two` ids in an array and use PHP's [`array_unique` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Then loop over this new array and get the user details or just use `WHERE user_id IN (id1, id2, id3 ...)`.

Comment: any idea how to use a UNION with SELECT DISTINCT and only retrieve one user id for each subquery. How to do this in my code?

Comment: gwc has done this with minimal number of queries and taken it a little further than I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Not better solution but you can use:

```
.....

$friends_array = array();

while ($run_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_friends)) {

    $friend_user_id = $run_friends['user_id'];

    if(!in_array($friend_user_id, $friends_array)) {

        $friends_array[] = $friend_user_id;

    }
}

print_r($friends_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try fetching all records in an array like

```
$variable = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

then try [removing duplicate values from that array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing to do would be to use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$run_friends = array_unique($runfriends);
$friend_user_id = $run_friends['user_id'];
```

Comment: looks nice, but I dont know where to use this in my code. could you be more specific?

Comment: in the last while loop

Answer (score 0):

this is untested and partly sudo code but i would take this approach to avoid running queries within loops

(the theory should be sound)

```
<?php
//load your friends
$friends = (SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one`='$session_user_id' OR `user_two`='$session_user_id')

//build array of your friends id's
$friendsOfMine = array()
for ($i = 0, $max = count($friends); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $friendsOfMine[] = ($friends[$i]['user_one'] == $session_user_id) ? 
        $friends[$i]['user_two'] : 
        $friends[$i]['user_one'];
}

$mightKnow = array();
//load your frineds friends
$frOfFr = (SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one` IN(implode(',', $friendsOfMine)) OR `user_two` IN(implode(',', $friendsOfMine)))

//build array of friends of friends id's
for ($i = 0, $max = count($frOfFr); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $mightKnow[] = (in_array(frOfFr[$i]['user_one'])) ? 
        $mightKnow[$i]['user_two'] : 
        $mightKnow[$i]['user_one'];
}

//load users that are in the array of frineds of friends but are not you
$friendsOfFriends = ("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` IN(" . implode(',',$mightKnow) . ") AND `user_id` NOT `user_id` IN(" . implode(',',$friendsOfMine) . ") AND `user_id` != '" . $session_user_id . "' ")
?>
```

on another note i would very much advise using PDO for your database connection